# Extract bit sequences of arbitrary length from byte[] array efficiently

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm looking for the most efficient way of extracting (unsigned) bit sequences of arbitrary length (0 <= length <= 16) at arbitrary position. The skeleton class show how my current implementation essentially handles the problem:

```
public abstract class BitArray {

byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
int bitGet;

public BitArray() {
}

public void readNextBlock(int initialBitGet, int count) {
    // substitute for reading from an input stream 
    for (int i=(initialBitGet>>3); i<=count; ++i) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) i;
    }
    prepareBitGet(initialBitGet, count);
}

public abstract void prepareBitGet(int initialBitGet, int count);

public abstract int getBits(int count);

static class Version0 extends BitArray {
    public void prepareBitGet(int initialBitGet, int count) {
        bitGet = initialBitGet;
    }

    public int getBits(int len) {
        // intentionally gives meaningless result
        bitGet += len;
        return 0;
    }
}

static class Version1 extends BitArray {
    public void prepareBitGet(int initialBitGet, int count) {
        bitGet = initialBitGet - 1;
    }

    public int getBits(int len) {
        int byteIndex = bitGet;
        bitGet = byteIndex + len;
        int shift = 23 - (byteIndex & 7) - len;
        int mask = (1 << len) - 1;
        byteIndex >>= 3;
        return (((bytes[byteIndex] << 16) | 
               ((bytes[++byteIndex] & 0xFF) <<  8) |
                (bytes[++byteIndex] & 0xFF)) >> shift) & mask;
    }
}

static class Version2 extends BitArray {
    static final int[] mask = { 0x0, 0x1, 0x3, 0x7, 0xF, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF,
                0x1FF, 0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF, 0xFFFF };

    public void prepareBitGet(int initialBitGet, int count) {
        bitGet = initialBitGet;
    }

    public int getBits(int len) {
        int offset = bitGet;
        bitGet = offset + len;
        int byteIndex = offset >> 3; // originally used /8
        int bitIndex = offset & 7;   // originally used %8
        if ((bitIndex + len) > 16) {
            return ((bytes[byteIndex] << 16 |
                    (bytes[byteIndex + 1] & 0xFF) << 8 |
                    (bytes[byteIndex + 2] & 0xFF)) >> (24 - bitIndex - len)) & mask[len];
        } else if ((offset + len) > 8) {
            return ((bytes[byteIndex] << 8 |
                    (bytes[byteIndex + 1] & 0xFF)) >> (16 - bitIndex - len)) & mask[len];
        } else {
            return (bytes[byteIndex] >> (8 - offset - len)) & mask[len];
        }
    }
}

static class Version3 extends BitArray {
    int[] ints = new int[2048];

    public void prepareBitGet(int initialBitGet, int count) {
        bitGet = initialBitGet;
        int put_i = (initialBitGet >> 3) - 1;
        int get_i = put_i;
        int buf;
        buf = ((bytes[++get_i] & 0xFF) << 16) |
              ((bytes[++get_i] & 0xFF) <<  8) |
               (bytes[++get_i] & 0xFF);
        do {
            buf = (buf << 8) | (bytes[++get_i] & 0xFF);
            ints[++put_i] = buf;
        } while (get_i < count);
    }

    public int getBits(int len) {
        int bit_idx = bitGet;
        bitGet = bit_idx + len;
        int shift = 32 - (bit_idx & 7) - len;
        int mask = (1 << len) - 1;
        int int_idx = bit_idx >> 3;
        return (ints[int_idx] >> shift) & mask;
    }
}

static class Version4 extends BitArray {
    int[] ints = new int[1024];

    public void prepareBitGet(int initialBitGet, int count) {
        bitGet = initialBitGet;
        int g = initialBitGet >> 3;
        int p = (initialBitGet >> 4) - 1;
        final byte[] b = bytes;
        int t = (b[g]  <<  8) | (b[++g] & 0xFF);
        final int[] i = ints;
        do {
            i[++p] = (t = (t << 16) | ((b[++g] & 0xFF) <<8) | (b[++g] & 0xFF));
        } while (g < count);
    }

    public int getBits(final int len) {
        final int i;
        bitGet = (i = bitGet) + len;
        return (ints[i >> 4] >> (32 - len - (i & 15))) & ((1 << len) - 1);
    }
}

public void benchmark(String label) {
    int checksum = 0;
    readNextBlock(32, 1927);
    long time = System.nanoTime();
    for (int pass=1<<18; pass>0; --pass) {
        prepareBitGet(32, 1927);
        for (int i=2047; i>=0; --i) {
            checksum += getBits(i & 15);
        }
    }
    time = System.nanoTime() - time;
    System.out.println(label+" took "+Math.round(time/1E6D)+" ms, checksum="+checksum);
    try { // avoid having the console interfere with our next measurement
        Thread.sleep(369);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

public static void main(String[] argv) {
    BitArray test;
    // for the sake of getting a little less influence from the OS for stable measurement
    Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    while (true) {
        test = new Version0();
        test.benchmark("no implementaion");
        test = new Version1();
        test.benchmark("Durandal's (original)");
        test = new Version2();
        test.benchmark("blitzpasta's (adapted)");
        test = new Version3();
        test.benchmark("MSN's (posted)");
        test = new Version4();
        test.benchmark("MSN's (half-buffer modification)");
        System.out.println("--- next pass ---");
    }
}
}
```

This works, but I'm looking for a **more efficient solution (performance wise)**. The byte array is guaranteed to be relatively small, between a few bytes up to a max of ~1800 bytes. The array is read exactly once (completely) between each call to the read method. There is no need for any error checking in getBits(), such as exceeding the array etc.

---

It seems my initial question above isn't clear enough. A "bit sequence" of N bits forms an integer of N bits, and I need to extract those integers with minimal overhead. I have no use for strings, as the values are either used as lookup indices or are directly fed into some computation. So basically, the skeleton shown above is a real class and getBits() signature shows how the rest of the code interacts with it.

---

Extendet the example code into a microbenchmark, included blitzpasta's solution (fixed missing byte masking). On my old AMD box it turns out as ~11400ms vs ~38000ms. FYI: Its the divide and modulo operations that kill the performance. If you replace **/8** with **>>3** and **%8** with **&7**, both solutions are pretty close to each other (jdk1.7.0ea104).

---

There seemed to be a bit confusion about how and what to work on. The first, original post of the example code included a read() method to indicate where and when the byte buffer was filled. This got lost when the code was turned into the microbench. I re-introduced it to make this a little clearer.
The idea is to beat all existing versions by adding another subclass of BitArray which need to implement getBits() and prepareBitGet(), the latter may be empty. **Do not change the benchmarking to give your solution an advantage, the same could be done for all the existing solutions, making this a completely moot optimization! (really!!)**

I added a Version0, which does nothing but increment the bitGet state. It always returns 0 to get a rough idea how big the benchmark overhead is. Its only there for comparison.

Also, an adaption on MSN's idea was added (Version3). To keep things fair and comparable for all competitors, the byte array filling is now part of the benchmark, as well as a preparatory step (see above). Originally MSN's solution did not do so well, there was lots of overhead in preparing the int[] buffer. I took the liberty of optimizing the step a little, which turned it into a fierce competitor :)
You might also find that I de-convoluted your code a little. Your getBit() could be condensed into a 3-liner, probably shaving off one or two percent. I deliberately did this to keep the code readable and because the other versions aren't as condensed as possible either (again for readability).

---

**Conclusion** (code example above update to include versions based on all applicable contributions). On my old AMD box (Sun JRE 1.6.0_21), they come out as:

V0 no implementaion took **5384** ms
V1 Durandal's (original) took **10283** ms
V2 blitzpasta's (adapted) took **12212** ms
V3 MSN's (posted) took **11030** ms
V4 MSN's (half-buffer modification) took **9700** ms

Notes: In this benchmark an average of 7.5 bits is fetched per call to getBits(), and each bit is only read once. Since V3/V4 have to pay a high initialization cost, they tend to show better runtime behavior with more, shorter fetches (and consequently worse the closer to the maximum of 16 the average fetch size gets). Still, V4 stays slightly ahead of all others in *all* scenarios.
In an actual application, the cache contention must be taken into account, since the extra space needed for V3/v4 may increase cache misses to a point where V0 would be a better choice. If the array is to be traversed more than once, V4 should be favored, since it fetches faster than every other and the costly initialization is amortized after the fist pass.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that /8 and %8 is way slower than >>3 and &7. Now I do.

Comment: This puzzled me, too, so I investigated. For the modulo, the JIT has no way of knowing that we only have positive values, and the results of %8 and &7 differ for negative values. For the integer divide, its similar. The shift is off by one for almost all value (except those that have 0's in the last four bits). So while one might intuitively assume the JIT would optimize this, it can not as it would potentially alter the results.

Comment: "most efficient way" in space? or in computation time? If you have space you could trade-off space by CPU by calculating the answers ahead in arrays and then only fetch array values.

Comment: Most efficient = Number of CPU cycles spent, and lets choose randomly: no more than 500% of the examples memory consumption. If intermediated buffers help, knock yourself out - but please keep the constraints from the original question in mind (sequential read once).

Comment: Just a side node: Before you compare the speed of the different implementations, make sure that they produce the result that you really want. When I initialized the `Version1` and asked it for 8 bits, it replied with `1`. Since the byte array starts with a `0`, I would have expected that first.

Comment: Thats a messy detail of Version1's implementation, it assumes the bit index to point at the last bit it returned, making it incapable to properly address array index 0, bit 7 (bitGet = -1). The benchmark compensates for this with the initialBitGet parameter. It wouldn't be hard to change it to work with bitGet pointing to the next bit to get, like blitzpastas solution does (and vice versa). In the context where I original developed getBits(), this addressing scheme was more practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, depending on how far you want to go down the time vs. memory see-saw, you can allocate a side table of every 32-bits at every 16-bit offset and then do a mask and shift based on the 16-bit offset:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];   
int bitGet;   
unsigned int dwords[] = new unsigned int[2046];

public BitArray() {   
    for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; ++i) {   
        bytes[i] = (byte) i;   
    }   

    for (int i= 0; i<dwords.length; ++i) {
        dwords[i]= 
            (bytes[i    ] << 24) | 
            (bytes[i + 1] << 16) | 
            (bytes[i + 2] <<  8) | 
            (bytes[i + 3]);
    }
}   

int getBits(int len)
{
    int offset= bitGet;
    int offset_index= offset>>4;
    int offset_offset= offset & 15;

    return (dwords[offset_index] >> offset_offset) & ((1 << len) - 1);
}
```

You avoid the branching (at the cost of quadrupling your memory footprint). And is looking up the mask really that much faster than (1 << len) - 1?

Comment: I initially had some trouble getting this to work, there are a few glitches in getBits(), but still the idea looks good (see edited microbench). I'm not sure how you intendet to calculate the shift value (offset_offset = offset & 15) - I had to resort to a more complicated expression to get it to work.

Comment: Looking up the mask from a table seems to be a little *slower* than (1 << len) - 1. Replacing the lookup in blitzpastas solution speeds it up by ~3%. I also played with your code a little more. It turns out that you can get away with half as much extra buffer (since getBits is constrainted to fetch 16 bits max). For every odd dword in the buffer one can substitute the following even dword and simply shift 8 bits less. Only requires a slight modification to the buffer preparation and different shift/mask values in getBits, so it runs at almost exactly the same speed.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the unsigned bit sequence as an int.

```
static final int[] lookup = {0x0, 0x1, 0x3, 0x7, 0xF, 0x1F, 0x3F, 0x7F, 0xFF, 0x1FF, 0x3FF, 0x7FF, 0xFFF, 0x1FFF, 0x3FFF, 0x7FFF, 0xFFFF };

/*
 * bytes: byte array, with the bits indexed from 0 (MSB) to (bytes.length * 8 - 1) (LSB)
 * offset: index of the MSB of the bit sequence.
 * len: length of bit sequence, must from range [0,16].
 * Not checked for overflow
 */
static int getBitSeqAsInt(byte[] bytes, int offset, int len){

    int byteIndex = offset / 8;
    int bitIndex = offset % 8;
    int val;

    if ((bitIndex + len) > 16) {
        val = ((bytes[byteIndex] << 16 | bytes[byteIndex + 1] << 8 | bytes[byteIndex + 2]) >> (24 - bitIndex - len)) & lookup[len];
    } else if ((offset + len) > 8) {
        val = ((bytes[byteIndex] << 8 | bytes[byteIndex + 1]) >> (16 - bitIndex - len)) & lookup[len];
    } else {
        val = (bytes[byteIndex] >> (8 - offset - len)) & lookup[len];
    }

    return val;
}
```

If you want it as a String (modification of Margus' answer).

```
static String getBitSequence(byte[] bytes, int offset, int len){

    int byteIndex = offset / 8;
    int bitIndex = offset % 8;
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();        

    outer:
    for(int i = byteIndex; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
        for(int j = (1 << (7 - bitIndex)); j > 0; j >>= 1) {
            if(count == len) {
                break outer;
            }                
            if((bytes[byteIndex] & j) == 0) {
                result.append('0');
            } else {
                result.append('1');
            }
            ++count;
        }
        bitIndex = 0;
    }
    return  result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks very similar to mine, only you get the mask for the part allocated in the int from a lookup table while I build it on the fly "(1 << count) - 1".  As far as I can tell the optimization to look if the sequence covers 1, 2 or 3 bytes is actually slowing the code - removing that its practically equal to my code.

Comment: Included your version into my microbenchmark (there was some byte masking missing which I took the libery of adding). The performance differences are... astounding.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Just wondering why can't you use `java.util.BitSet;`</s>

Basically what you can do, is to read the whole data as `byte[]`, convert it to binary in `string` format and use string utilities like `.substring()` to do the work. This will also work `bit sequences > 16`.

Lets say you have 3 bytes: `1, 2, 3` and you want to extract bit sequence from 5th to 16th bit.

**Number   Binary**

```
1      00000001
2      00000010
3      00000011
```

**Code example:**

```
public static String getRealBinary(byte[] input){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (byte c : input) {
        for (int n =  128; n > 0; n >>= 1){
            if ((c & n) == 0)
                sb.append('0');
            else sb.append('1');
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte bytes[] = new byte[]{1,2,3};
    String sbytes = getRealBinary(bytes);
    System.out.println(sbytes);
    System.out.println(sbytes.substring(5,16));
}
```

**Output:**

```
000000010000001000000011
00100000010
```

**Speed:**

I did a testrun for **1m** times and on my computer it took **0.995s**, so its reasonably very fast:

Code to repeat the test yourself:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    byte bytes[] = new byte[4];
    long start, time, total=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        r.nextBytes(bytes);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        getRealBinary(bytes).substring(5,16);
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        total+=time;
    }
    System.out.println("It took " +total + "ms");
}
```

Comment: BitSet doesn't offer a method to get consecutive bits as int, I would still have to implement a getBits() of my own, still managing my own bitGet index and calling BitSet.get(index) for every single bit - that contradicts my definition of efficient. I'm intrested in speed, not flexibility here.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough, I'm looking to extract into integers, no other fancy transformations.

Answer (score 0):

You want at most 16 bits, taken from an array of bytes.  16 bits can span at most 3 bytes.
Here's a possible solution:

```
    int GetBits(int bit_index, int bit_length) {
          int byte_offset = bit_index >> 3;
          return ((((((byte_array[byte_offset]<<8)
                    +byte_array[byte_offset+1])<<8)
                    +byte_array[byte_offset+2]))
                   >>(24-(bit_index&7)+bit_length))))
                  &((1<<bit_length)-1);
         }
```

[Untested]

If you call this a lot you should  precompute the 24-bit values for the 3 concatenated bytes, and store those into an int array.

I'll observe that if you are coding this in C on an x86, you don't even need to precompute the 24 bit array; simply access the by te array at the desire offset as a 32 bit value.  The x86 will do unaligned fetches just fine.  [commenter noted that endianess mucks this up, so it isn't an answer, OK, do the 24 bit version.]

Comment: You seem to have missed the Java tag :) If I'm not mistaken, fetching simply a dword on x86 wouldn't be all that simple, since its a little endian architecture. There are two typos in the code example (first shift should be 16 and the third array access is missing a +2 to the index). Adding that its just a condensation of whats in the question under Version1. Oh and in Java bytes are signed and silently promoted to int, so the 2nd and 3rd byte need to be masked with 0xFF.

Comment: First shift is 8 bits, then 2nd byte added, and that pair is shifted left 8. If your machine has a barrel shifter, this won't matter, but if it shifts short distances faster than long it matters. Yes, dropped the +2, edited to correct. If bytes are promoted as signed (stupid Java) you can alway just copy them to "ints" before you start to avoid the sign masking junk, and that should make it competitive. Now that I've scrolled version 1 right a few hundred characters (wasnt easy where the scroll bar was) I see you did the same sort of thing.  The 7 line answer got lost in your huge example :-{

Comment: +1 for reminding me that shift distance may make a difference on some machines. The example was once small, but the way things developed ... well it ended up this way. Unfortunately Java can not perform *any* unsigned casts to a wider type, that leaves us Java guys with no choice other than masking :(

Comment: Java might insist on signed casts, but if you have an 8 bit value stored in an int (maybe you got that masking it!) you don't need to mask the value fetched from the int. However, I think the 24-bits-precomputed is by far your best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 7 `BitSet` has the [`toLongArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#toLongArray()) method, which I believe will do exactly what the question asks for:

```
int subBits = (int) bitSet.get(lowBit, highBit).toLongArray()[0];
```

This has the advantage that it works with sequences larger than ints or longs. It has the performance disadvantage that a new `BitSet` object must be allocated, and a new array object to hold the result.

It would be really interesting to see how this compares with the  other methods in the benchmark.